# Nginx : AWS Route 53 : ELB : naked redirect

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

**Setup**
I have two rails app instances running in Opsworks Layer.
I am using Route 53 and an ELB to route traffic to my Layer.

**Objective**
To redirect naked domain traffic to my www domain. 
chicken.com -> www.chicken.com

**What I tried**
I Alter my nginx conf (on one instance) to solve this problem. I added the following:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name chicken.com;
 return 301 $scheme://www.chicken.com$request_uri;
}
... rest of config here
```

**Result**
Instance is no longer hittable by its IP.

ELB marked the instance I had altered as "Out of Service" since it could no longer be reached by IP (the health check fails).

**Question**
How can I route naked domains to www domains yet keep my ELB health checks happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup something that'll return 2xx on the health check, currently the 301 is making the ELB think it's out of service, you could put something like this

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name chicken.com;

 location ^~ /health {
   proxy_pass http://my_proxy;
 }

 location / {
   return 301 $scheme://www.chicken.com$request_uri;
 }

}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name www.chicken.com;

 location / {
   proxy_pass http://my_proxy;
 }
}
```

Comment: could you explain my_proxy.. a bit more, I dont think I get it.

Comment: I want /health to just be served, and everything else to return 301 to www.chicken.com. I am not sure how the proxy_pass to http://my_proxy does that.. is there an idea of http://<self>? in nginx?

Comment: sorry, so many configurations use proxy_pass that I thought I could use it as the example... basically -- however you're serving your site, that is the "rest of config" bit you mention -- goes inside the locations bit instead of proxy_pass

Answer (score 0):

Or more simple way.

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name chicken.com;

 location /status {
        stub_status   on;
 }

 location / {
   return 301 $scheme://www.chicken.com$request_uri;
 }

}
```